# Hi Team, am new in groovy, i know that its simple, but I got confused.in my controller i have 2list of values. thats shown like

Tags: grails, groovy

`Ratios:[2,9,3.5]`//double value//  AND `uom:[1,2,3,4]`

now need to get these through map like this,

```
Ratios:[2]`Ratios:[9]`Ratios:[3.5]`

uom:[1]`uom:[2]`uom:[3]`uom:[4]`
```

and Finally need to associate all these in one array , LIKE

```
MyArray[ Ratios:[2]
         Ratios:[9]
         Ratios:[3.5]
         uom:[1]
         uom:[2]
         uom:[3]
         uom:[4]   ]
```

how do i get like this.PLEASE HELP ME
my code is,

```
def jsonSlurperjson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper();
            def jsonData = [];
            def Ratios;
            def UOM;
            def RatioMap=[];

            def Obj = jsonSlurperjson.parseText(params.Selected);

            if (Obj.uom!= null || Obj.uom!= "") {
                UOM= Obj.uom;
            }
            if (Obj.ratio != null || Obj.ratio != "") {
                Ratios = Obj.ratio;
            }
            for(int i=0; i<Ratios.size(); i++) {
                RatioMap.add(Ratios[i]);

            }
```

Comment: Is `Ratios:[2]Ratios:[9]Ratios:[3.5]` supposed to be a `Map` with 3 entries in it?

Comment: no.it will be looped.so we can expect more entries in it

Comment: "no.it will be looped.so we can expect more entries in it " - Are all of the keys supposed to be "Ratios"?

Comment: Are all of the keys supposed to be "Ratios"? – yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect over both lists to create the maps and add the two
resulting lists to get the final list

```
[2,9,3.5].collect{ [Ratios: it] } + [1,2,3,4].collect{ [uom: it] }
// → [[Ratios:2], [Ratios:9], [Ratios:3.5], [uom:1], [uom:2], [uom:3], [uom:4]]
```